# Condensing nested if-statements with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing, match, vlookup

The blue columns is the data given and the red columns is what is being calculated.  Then the table to the right is what I am referencing.  So, F2 will be calculated by the following steps:

1. Look at the Machinery column (D), if the cell contains LF, select column K, otherwise select column L
2. Look at the Grade column (E), if the cell contains RG, select rows 4:8, otherwise select rows 9:12.
3. Look at the Species column (A), if the cell contains MS, select rows 5 and 10, otherwise.......
4. Where every the most selected cell is in columns K and L, copy into column F.
5. Multiply column F by column C.

I don't want to make another column for my final result.  I did in the picture to show the two steps separately.  So column F should be the final answer (F2 = 107.33).  The reference table can be formatted differently as well.

At first, I tried using nested-if statements, but realized that I would have like 20+ if statements for all the different outcomes.  I think I would want to use the SEARCH function to find weather of not the cell contains a specific piece of information.  Then I would probably use some sort of combination of match, if, v-lookup, index, search, but I am not sure how to condense these.

Any suggestion?

[image]

Comment: Why `F2=83.20`? According to your logic, because MAchinery does not contain `LF`, select column L. And because Grade is RG, selection is `L4:L8`. and because Species contains MS, it should be row 5 or 10, but row 10 is out of range `L4:L8`, so, why not should the answer be `L5` in the first case? I'm not complaining, I'm just trying to understand your logic to be able to help

Comment: Agreed, I would also expect `F2` to be equal `104.00`

Comment: You are correct.  My mistake.  `F2` should be `104.00`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUMPRODUCT is the function you need. I quickly created some test data on the lines of what you shared like this:

[image]

Then I entered the below formula in cell F2

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(($I$4:$I$9=E2)*($J$4:$J$9=LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2)-1))*IF(ISERROR(FIND("LF",D2,1)),$L$4:$L$9,$K$4:$K$9))
```

The formula may look a little scary but is indeed very simple as each sub formula checks for a condition that you would want to evaluate. So, for example,

```
($I$4:$I$9=E2)
```

is looking for rows that match `GRADE` of the current row in range `$I$4:$I$9` and so on. The `*` ensures that the arrays thus returned are multiplied and only the value where all conditions are `true` remains.

Since some of your conditions require looking for partial content like in `Species` and `Machine`, I have used `Left` and `Find` functions within `Sumproduct`

This formula simply returns the value from either column K or L based on the matching conditions and you may easily extend it or add more conditions.

Comment: I believe at the end of your equation the `K` and `L` arrays should be switched.  Also, I did not have this in my sub-example, but in my data set I sometimes do not have a `" "` in column J.  So the formula returns `#VALUE`.

Comment: If you notice, I am checking for ISERROR when trying to FIND "LF". So, if LF is available ISERROR returns False and hence we return the K column in False part of the formula. Therefore, K and L seem to be correctly placed. As far as not having a space in column J, you have two options: 1. you may use full value in column J i.e. for example MS ITP, SDM ITP etc. and then simply change the matching condition to $J$4:$J$9=A2.  2. Use ISERROR function within that part of the formula as well. But my suggestion would be to go with option 1 as the other will result in a very complex formula.

Comment: You are correct, I had my columns flipped around.  And, yes I decided to go with option 1.  I tried option 2 at first, but wasn't able to figure it out.